# What does the following code mean in javascript?

Tags: javascript

What does the following code means in javascript

`config = config || {}`

Comment: If `config` is defined and is not `==` falsey value, use that or init as `{}` empty object..

Comment: if config undefined set config to an empty {}

Answer (score 3):

```
config = config || {}
```

Basically it is trying to initialize the `config` to an empty object `{}` if it hasn't already been initialized or initialized to one of the following values

- **undefined**
- **null**
- **""**
- **false**
- **0**

if the config is `undefined`, `null`, `""`, `false` or `0`, it will get a new value as `{}`

For example, following will be the scenarios where the first

```
var config = undefined; config =  config || {}; //output Object {}
var config = null; config =  config || {};//output Object {}
var config = 0; config =  config || {}; //output Object {}
var config = false; config =  config || {}; //output Object {}
var config = ""; config =  config || {}; //output Object {}
```

So, the **OR condition** is executed as if the `Boolean(config)` it false (it will be false if it is one of these values (**undefined** , **null**, **""**, **false**, **0** ) then it will execute the next statement `{}` and assign that value to `config`.

Comment: Or `if it hasn't already been initialized or It is initialized as falsey value...` I guess you need to edit...

Comment: @RayonDabre thanks, made the edit

Comment: I downvoted because this question has been answered 100 times before. And when you keep answering duplicates like this all the information will be spread out over 100+ questions making finding all the information harder.

Comment: @PeeHaa sure, fair enough. I will go through the original question and remove my answer if info I have given is already given in the original link.

Answer (score 1):

```
var config = config || {}
```

meaning that if config is false (config is null or "" or nan or undefined ) set variable as empty object if else set it as config

```
var config = config && {}
```

meaning that if config is false (config is null or "" or nan or undefined ) set variable as config object if else set it as empty object