# What does mean of variable in javaScript?

Tags: javascript

javaScript(variable)

```
var s = s || {};
s.c = {};
```

what purposes it will be use?

Comment: If object is defined, use it. If not then declare empty object.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35913820/what-does-the-following-code-mean-in-javascript/35913842#35913842

Comment: @Praveen I want  to know about second line when it used.

Answer (score 4):

`var s = s || {};`

This means that if `s` is `null`, `undefined` or `false` (it computes to false), then an empty object `{}` will be assigned to `s`, so that the second line would not cause an error.

But this notation is inacurate. It should be something like:

```
var s = (typeof s == 'object') ? s : {};
```

because in the first example if `s` is a number the second line will still cause an error.

In the second example notation `A ? B : C;` is equal to:

```
if(A){
    B;
}else{
    C;
}
```

Comment: Kindly do not answer dupes... Instead close them.